# XNA windows phone 7 how to create a load page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

How to I create a load page?

Such as a progress bar or some sort of control that will display on how long will it take to load?

Answer (score 0):

Progress bars are generally not a good idea unless you can with a high degree of certainty know exactly how long something is going to take.

Instead creating some sort of loading image is generally a better idea and I'm sure you've seen the switch in the industry to this style. (A spinning circle on the tab in Google Chrome for example when the page is loading, or the rotating circles in the bottom right of the screen for most Xbox 360 games).

As for how to do it, there isn't a lot of complexity to it. Your game runs in a loop and most long running things like loading happen in the background so all you have to do is keep checking in every Update call if that thing you're waiting on is still happening. If it is continue showing the "loading" graphic. Ideally you'd be handling that with some sort of game state indicator so that all your game has to do is switch to a "loading" or "waiting" state and the game would automatically drawing the standard waiting/loading screen for your game.

For more understanding of Game State I've got a fairly lengthy tutorial that you can read on the subject called "[The State of Things](http://xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thestateofthings/thestateofthings.shtml)"